Marketing Cloud Streaming Updates - Error 401
We are implementing Streaming Updates for a client and have encountered a couple issues/errors when testing the implementation. We are mainly facing error 401 - Unauthorized. Please see the screenshots below of the setup we are using for testing in Postman:


We have made sure that the apikey is valid, and we have also done a fair amount of research on the topic. SF Support says that they only recommend ensuring we are not doing a client-side implementation to prevent exposing sensitive data.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Please only use images to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way. Instead of using images for code, copy and paste the code as text into your question.

Tbh I have never managed to get this to work in Postman. You will need to whitelist the IP address of the client, and even after whitelisting my public IP, it still showed 401.

When testing this you should supply actual test values.
A valid URL for example is necessary
{
    "api_key": "XXXXXXX",
    "payload": {
        "item": "12292",
        "unique_id": "74902",
        "item_type": "product",
        "name": "Sample Product Name",
        "url": "https://www.google.com",
        "brand": "Sameple brand name"
    }
}

